# Heroku deployment using Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to push a simple rails app to Heroku that uses MongoDB. My Gemfile contains the following line:

gem "mongo"

When pushing the app to Heroku it error's out with: **no such file to load -- mongo**

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.3
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- mongo (LoadError)
```

Here is my whole gemfile:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
source 'http://gemcutter.org'

gem "rails", "3.0.0"
#gem 'rails', :git => 'http://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem "mongo_mapper"
gem 'mongoid', '2.0.0.beta.20'
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
gem 'heroku', '1.13.7'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont need either of these lines in your Gemfile:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
```

Neither of those are required for bundler to update or install your gems.

Also, is there a reason why you're installing both mongoid and mongo_mapper?

Comment: Thank you - i Honestly have no idea why i'm installing both. First Rails app for me and I had followed two different guides that showed how to do authentication with rails and the other on how to connect it with mongo.

Comment: btw - this was a two part fix 1) remove the 2 require lines 2) delete Gemfile.lock after which i was able to push the app to heroku.

Comment: You shouldn't have to ever delete your lockfile, when you update your gemfile just do `bundle update` and that will update the lockfile and fix any gem dependency issues.

Comment: there must of been something weird going on because even though the line 'require "mongo"' was no longer presented, it kept saying it was so by removing the lockfile it got fixed. It was cached from what I cna tell.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another approach that you can use, is to use something like https://mongolab.com, connect you application with the database on the cloud, and then make the deployment (only the rails application).I've been using MongoLabs for a while, and works pretty good, you can check your collections directly from there (you don't need to use the JS shell). This is just a suggestion, to make the deployment easier :)